# iPhone what kind of animation would imitate rotating an object if I have 4 still images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, quartz-graphics

I have 4 UIImages of an object : front, left, back and right. **I would like to be able to imitate "rotating" this flat UIImage as a user pushes a button.**

Currently I just fade different sides in/out, but am interested if there's some kind of UIView curling animation or transform that would "rotate" a flat image around one axis, and then fade in the image for the subsequent side. While not full 3D, it may look decent.

Is this kind of animation possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered scaling/squeezing the image towards that axis, and expanding the next image in from the opposite axis? For example, if `x` were to represent your front image, `y` represented your right image, and you rotated right (from `x` to `y`), you'd have the transition:

```
xxxxxx -> xxxxyy -> xxyyyy -> yyyyyy
```

This would give the impression of a cube rotating about its center (behind your images). You mention curling and fading, so I'm not sure that this is exactly what you want, but I think it'd be an easy way to transition between images.

Comment: +1. an alternative may be to use a `UIView` animation and setting the transition effect with `setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:`, but I'm not sure this will give a better result.

Comment: This might work. Imitating a rotating cube may involve some kind of translation and skew animation, I will need to investigate what is involved in this. If I remember correctly,view transitions for UIView were full-screen operations, while I need to rotate an image view on a screen.

Comment: @AlexStone You can apply transitions to any UIView, so also to subviews. No need to be fullscreen animation.